# Javascript get data from Neo4j filter by boolean property

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I use javascript, neo4j, apoc to load data.
    I saved data with property boolean.
    I want to receive only data where adult = true.

```
//Upload data 
CALL apoc.load.json('myFile.json') YIELD value 
UNWIND value.products as p  
MERGE (pr:Person{name: value.name, adult: value.adult}) 
MERGE (a:Address {street: p.street}) 
MERGE (pr)-[:live]->(a)

If I do this query I receive data with true and false.
Could you help me to find a mistake?

//Get adult = true
MATCH (pr:Person) --> (a:Address) 
WHERE pr.adult=TRUE
RETURN pr.name. a.street
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
WHERE pr.adult=TRUE
```

With this:

```
WHERE pr.adult=true
```

If you're storing exactly TRUE, then it's string not boolean value and you'll need:

```
WHERE pr.adult='TRUE'
```

---

Also, there's a typo in your code:

```
RETURN pr.name. a.street
```

It should be:

```
RETURN pr.name, a.street
```